# Vacuum state in "in-in" formalism

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, correlation-functions

While dealing with correlation functions of fields in cosmology, we often use the formula,

$⟨Q(\eta)⟩=⟨0|\overline{T}\left[\exp\left(i\int^{\eta}_{\infty}H^I(\eta')d\eta'\right)\right]Q^I(\eta)T\left[\exp\left(-i\int^{\eta}_{\infty}H^I(\eta')d\eta'\right)\right]|0⟩$

where "$I$" denotes the interaction picture and $T$ denotes time ordering. $|0⟩$ is the Bunch Davies vacuum state. However, what is the state with which the expectation value of the LHS is being calculated? If it is the interacting vacuum state, (like we have in standard flat space qft) how is it projected onto the Bunch Davies vacuum state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation value is with respect to the interacting vacuum $|\Omega⟩$. What you want to calculate is this:

$$⟨\Omega|Q(\eta)|\Omega⟩=\frac{⟨0|\overline{T}\left[\exp\left(i\int^{\eta}_{\infty}H^I(\eta')d\eta'\right)\right] Q^I(\eta) \, T\left[\exp\left(-i\int^{\eta}_{\infty}H^I(\eta')d\eta'\right)\right]|0⟩}{⟨0|\overline{T}\left[\exp\left(i\int^{\eta}_{\infty}H^I(\eta')d\eta'\right)\right] T\left[ \exp\left(-i\int^{\eta}_{\infty}H^I(\eta')d\eta'\right)\right]|0⟩}$$

As you can see the denominator is 1, so we don't have a projector as in the in-out formalism.

Comment: How are you replacing $|\Omega⟩$ by the free Bunch Davies state on the right? The expression in the numerator is just the definition of $Q^I$ (I've been following the appendix of Weinberg's paper, 'Quantum Contributions to Cosmological Correlations', check eq. A.22).

Comment: Are you saying that there is some scalar factor $F$ such that $|\Omega⟩=F|0⟩$ where $F$ satisfies $F^*F=⟨0|\overline{T}...|0⟩$?

Comment: @SounakSinha See Peskin Schroeder equation 4.31, I am writing precisely that with appropriate contour ordering. Here the denominator is 1, and you are left with the numerator contribution only.

Comment: I don't understand how Peskin's equation holds here, it's true for an interacting Hamiltonian which doesn't have explicit time dependence, right? Here, it might not be the case.